# Key bindings e4

Tags: key, swt, key-bindings, e4

I have a problem with defining a new key binding in Eclipse 4. I want to access a button when the user press ALT+ARROW_LEFT.

I tried to create a new scheme but it doesn't work

Comment: What have you got in the 'Binding Contexts' and 'BindingTables' parts of your Application.e4xmi?

Comment: I resolved the problem :) ..
Off topic-ish there is some method which gets the key binding? 
For example if i press Ctrl+H i want to open a page and if i press it again to close that page .
I want to get the combination of keys and set it to true and if i press it again to set it  to false and close the page

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. Ask a new question with more details.